# Can I embed VBA userform into a website in html?

Tags: html, vba

I created USERFORM in VBA.
I want to embed it on WEB using HTML, so at the click of a button the USERFORM opens.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. VBA UserForms must be hosted by the application that hosts the VBA.

Theoretically, code could open a host application (such as Excel), which in turn could show the UserForm. But in practise this is not very practical since such applications should not be used in a server environment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this will work.  VBA is designed to be run on a desktop machine, not a server machine.  Maybe SharePoint can offer this kind of functionality, not sure.  Or, consider switching to .NET.  There are other technologies that can do this as well, but Excel/VBA is not one of them.